# Fazer o push dentro de um for loop não incrementa um let declarado em seu escopo?

Tags: javascript, for, scope

Estava lendo a série [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/scope%20%26%20closures/ch5.md#loops--closure) que diz o seguinte sobre `let` declarados em `for` loops:

> There's a special behavior defined for `let` declarations used in the head of a for-loop. This behavior says that the variable will be declared not just once for the loop, **but each iteration**. And, it will, helpfully, be initialized at each subsequent iteration with the value from the end of the previous iteration.

Agora, eu tentei isso noutro dia:

```
var numeros = [4, 5, 6];
var n = [];
for (let l = n.length; l < numeros.length;) {
    n.push(numeros[l] * 2);
}
// [8, 8, 8, 8, 8,...] loop infinito
```

Contudo, isto funciona como esperado:

```
for (;n.length < numeros.length;) {
    n.push(numeros[n.length] * 2);
}
// [8, 10, 12]
```

É interessante o que acontece misturando os dois casos, pois o `l` não muda a cada iteração:

[image: for-loop-let.gif]

Esperava que `l` mudasse em todos os casos, por que não é o que acontece?

Comment: Eu vou te pergunta então de maneira simples, porque a pergunta não tem também nada a ver com closure, mas, sim o link tem exemplos de tal, qual é a sua real duvida? é saber se o `let` da variável é sempre redeclarado em cada passagem no `for` ou qual é a diferença entre as duas formas? o que você espera como resposta, porque é muito fácil falar que eu sai do foco, mas, a outra resposta também saiu totalmente do foco e dizer que existem maneiras de fazer diferente não é o foco da pergunta.

Comment: A pergunta é a que está acima mesmo, por que o `let` não é redeclarado a cada iteração. Ainda não entendi o porquê. Suspeito que seja como você falou, que só o campo da incrementação/decrementação alteraria o valor do que é declarado ali na primeira expressão, e aí faz sentido com o exemplo do link, pois ele usa a terceira expressão do for. Contudo, acho que uma pesquisa mais dedicada na especificação do Ecma poderia trazer maior esclarecimento.

Comment: na minha visão se não quer saber de `closure` você quer saber a diferença entre os dois `for` da sua pergunta e isso talvez esteja confuso.

Comment: apesar que eu entendi, que a sua duvida é porque o `n` vai incrementando e você acha que esse valor está sendo passando novamente para `l`, e isso não vai acontecer, porque o primeiro só passa o valor inicial ... o seu incremento ou é feito no terceiro parâmetro que é o ideal ou no corpo do `for`!

Comment: Certo. Acho razoável. Vou dar uma olhada na especificação.

Comment: quando é feito um debug, por exemplo ele só passa na inicialização uma vez. entendeu?

Comment: Sim, entendi. Vocês enfatizaram bem isso.

Answer (score 2):

Porque esse local do `for` é exatamente para inicialização, ele só executa uma vez, ele não faz parte do laço em si, ele é um pré processamento que ocorre para começar o laço. É quase como se ele estivesse declarado antes do `for`, só é diferente por o escopo dele é só dentro do `for`.

Por que não muda o valor de `l`? Porque você não mandou mudar em lugar algum. A variável não vai mudar seu valor sozinha por mágica. Eu entendo que achou que a declaração ali (`let l = n.length`) seria executada em cada passo do laço e por isso a variável seria modificada com o novo tamanho do *array* (seu código foi esperto para criar uma situação interessante para mostrar isso), mas não é assim, faltou saber que justamente aquele trecho só é executado antes de começar o laço.

O código da condição e o código que determina o passo (em geral um incremento) que você não usou é executado em cada passo, sendo que o código de passo é executado antes da condição. E claro, tudo o que está dentro do bloco de código vinculado ao `for` também será executado todas as vezes.

Note que o contexto da explicação fala de *closures*, onde o uso de uma variável do laço tem fortes implicações, e aí a explicação faz sentido. Não que eu ache a explicação citada como um texto bem feito, dá a impressão errada. Eu não quero entrar em detalhes porque a pergunta é sobre o `for` e o código postado não tem uma *closure*, mas o que acontecerá é que cada *closure* terá um objeto diferente apontando para o valor de `i` de acordo com o seu valor no momento da criação da *closure*. Sem a *closure* isso não acontece e não há o efeito que está querendo demonstrar, mesmo que a variável estivesse sendo mudada.

Comment: No caso, não consegui entender a ligação com closures, mas sim que a variável declarada ali só pode ser alterada com a terceira expressão do `for` loop (incrementa/decrementa), assim como o @VirgilioNovik explicou na primeira linha.

Comment: Isso não é verdade também.

Comment: Bom, por que não?

Comment: Porque existem várias outras formas de alterar uma variável. Na resposta abaixo não está explicando o que você perguntou, está só falando o que fazer para não entrar em *loop* infinito que não é o foco da pergunta. Pra falar a verdade eu tenho minhas dúvidas se a citação que postou é realmente aquilo, em outras linguagens não é, pode ser apenas que o texto não tenha ficado bom e por isso mesmo causou o entendimento errado. Inclusive a ideia do texto só faz sentido no contexto de *closure* porque aí tem vários objetos sendo capturados, mas isso tem a ver com a *closure* e não o `for`.

Answer (score 1):

O motivo é porque não colocou o **incremento** (`l++`) e por isso do `loop` infinito, exemplo básico:

```js
var numeros = [4, 5, 6];
var n = [];
for (let l = 0; l < numeros.length;l++) {
    n.push(numeros[l] * 2);
}

console.log(n);
```

apesar que existem uma maneira muito mais prática de fazer isso:

```js
var numeros = [4, 5, 6];
var n = numeros.map(function(n) { return n * 2 });
console.log(n);
```

a segunda forma

```
for (;n.length < numeros.length;) {
    n.push(numeros[n.length] * 2);
}
```

funcionou porque o `n` vai aumentando o número de posições até adicionar todas do outro `array` e só tem a parte da condição que é a única coisa necessária para o termino desse `for`